# Transfer a file from Amazon EC2 to S3

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do I transfer one file from EC2 to S3?

I have a backup of a site that I wget'ed to my EC2. Now I just want to back it up in an S3 bucket. What's the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just because you're in EC2 doesn't mean you need to communicate with S3 in any special way, so you can use any of the prevelent S3 management tools.

You haven't said if you're using Linux/Windows or whatever.. but here are some options:

1. From a linux cmd line s3cmd is pretty easy to use and powerful: http://s3tools.org/s3cmd
2. If you're on a windows VM, you can just use s3fox (Firefox plugin) OR go the whole hog and use a full explorer type interface with http://cloudberrylab.com/default.aspx?page=s3-explorer-pro

Answer (score 0):

I use jets3t. It is a java tool, so I use it on all platforms, Linux, Windows, heck - even on an AS400 it worked :)